# Outlook meeting not showing participant categories

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

There seems to be an issue with some meetings in Outlook 2010.  Everyone shares there calendar with one another, and we would like the accepted and rejected participants to show up on the calendar item.  Some meetings will show this, and others will not.  I can't seem to figure out what a meeting needs to have or something to be able to show this information.

Please let me know if you find this confusing or needs clarification.